# Convergence in $L^1$ norm

Tags: lebesgue-integral

$(f_n), f$ are integrable. If $\int |f_n - f| \rightarrow 0$, then show that $\int_E f_n \rightarrow \int_E f$ for all measurable sets $E$ and that $\int f_n^+ \rightarrow \int f^+$.

Attempt: $$\left| \int f_n - \int f \,\right| \leq\int |f_n - f| \rightarrow 0 $$ which gives $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$. How do I get this down to measurable sets $E$.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Hint: $\int_E|g|\leq \int_X|g|$ where $X$ is your full measure space.

Comment: Oh thanks, I see how to get down to $E$. Any hint for the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: $\int_E|g|\leq \int_X|g|$ where $X$ is your full measure space.

Hint 2: using the fact that 
$$y^+=\max(y,0)=\frac{|y|+y}{2}$$
we can see that $y\longmapsto y^+$ is $1$-Lipschitz:
$$
|y^+-z^+|=\lvert\frac{|y|-|z|+y-z}{2} \rvert\leq\frac{||y|-|z||+|y-z|}{2}\leq |y-z|.
$$